# How can I get the same product from two different categories on the same URL?

Tags: magento2

How can I get the same product from two different categories on the same URL?
Like, I have two categories 1. Men, 2. Women.
And Also i have one Product 1. testdev.

Now i want the same URL for this product for two different categories when men product quantity is zero then get a product from women category but URL same.

like, http://domainexample.in/men/testdev.html
and manage stock automatically from men category to women

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: Yes but this is not my question of the answer my question is i have 2 same product and i have added this two same product into two different categories then how can i manage my product stock from both categories if one of stock will empty.

Answer (score 0):

On the Admin sidebar, go to `Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Search Engine Optimizations` and set `Use Categories Path for Product URLs` value to `No`. Remember to flush Magento cache.

More info is documentation: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/catalog-urls.html#configure-catalog-urls